# PHP syntax error that I cannot find

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

I have a file with the following php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
include_once("functions.php");
include_once("class/db.class.php");
$config = new config($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
$db = new db($config);
$db->openConnection();

switch ($_POST['mode']) {
    case 'update':
        if(mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET id_negozio = '".$_POST['negid']."', nome='".mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['nome']))."', cognome='".mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['cognome']))."', indirizzo='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['indirizzo'])."', CAP='".$_POST['cap']."', city='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city'])."', tel='".$_POST['tel']."', email='".strtolower($_POST['email'])."', provincia='".strtoupper($_POST['provincia'])."', data_nascita = '".$_POST['datanascita']."', luogo_nascita='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['luogonascita'])."', doc_number='".strtoupper($_POST['docnum'])."', doc_type='".$_POST['doctype']."', doc_data='".$_POST['docdata']."', cf='".strtoupper($_POST['cf'])."', doc_exp='".$_POST['doc_exp']."', doc_rilascio='".$_POST['doc_rilascio']."' WHERE id = ".$_POST['id']." ")){
            echo "ok";
        }
    break;

    case 'salvataggio_finale':
        if(mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET salvato = 1 WHERE id = ".$_POST['id']." ")){
            logit("Creato nuovo cliente.", $_POST['idneg']);
            echo "ok";
        }
    break;

    case 'del':
        if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = ".$_POST['id']." ")){
            logit("Eliminato cliente con id ".$_POST['id']."", $_POST['idneg']);
            echo "deleted";
        }
    break;
}
unset($db);
?>
```

On my server i have the error_log that shows 38 entries giving this error:

```
[..] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/.../filename.php on line 12
```

Where line 12 is the **if statement** after **case 'update'**
I don't see why I should not put the bracket or what the real error is.

Comment: Well, your database is gonna be pwned :D Escape the input.

Comment: Just tell me why some of your `$_POST` values are escaped and some are not?

Comment: What is the code of your include files? Your code seems to be correct.

Comment: @Jari because in Italy we have people name like D'Agostino Antonio and I have to do that so they can put the ' where they want

Comment: I can say one thing then: GG

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if `class/db.class.php` has a unclosed quotemark (") ?

Also be aware of possible sql injections when concatenating a POST variable into the query.

Comment: Ok, what shall I do then in order not the get injections?

Comment: I checked and can't see any error. I also opened it in NetBeans so that is catches errors, but... nothing.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all `$_POST[...]` variables should be enougth... Yes, it's probably not a quotemark problem, since then it should complaint about an invalid `UPDATE` keyword... but stilll it must be something in the includes, maybe you can post them here too